# OOP/PHP: Is it possible to have a default behaviour for every method of a class?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to get better with OOP patterns.

I have a class that generates XML for a set of data. It has different methods for different XML bodies, but every XML has the same header and each method needs to return the XML as a string.

I have made a private function, that constructs the header and returns the XML-object where the specific get-method adds her child-nodes according to needs. I have made a private function that beautifies the XML (if set) and closes it with a default "footer" block.

I am pondering if there is a pattern to optimize this and make sure, that both init_xml and prepeare_xml are both always called at the start and the end of each public method. Is it possible to construct the class in a way, that every public method call invokes 1st the header method and after adding the child-nodes the footer method?

Have one get_xml($type, $data) method that calls the specific get_?_xml methods according to $type? Or is there a better pattern?

I hope this raw example makes sense

```
class Foo{
  private $xml;

  public function get_bar_xml($data){
    $this->xml = $this->init_xml();

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
      $this->xml->addChild(key, $value);
    }

    return $this->prepare_xml();
  }

  //... set of similar methods following with different
  // child node creation

  private function init_xml(){
    //$this->xml header generation
  }

  private function prepare_xml(){
    //add footer nodes to $this->xml
    //format output if neccesary 

    return $this->xml;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like `Foo` is a singleton, or is at least instantiated only once and then produces many XML files? You should rather see one object instance as one XML document:

```
class Foo {
    protected $xml;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->xml = /* whatever */;
        // add headers
    }

    public function add($data) {
        // write $data to xml
    }

    public function asXML() {
        $this->writeFooter();
        return (string)$this->xml; // or whatever
    }
}
```

You can make this a base class, and have different kinds of documents extend it to customise only the `add` method to their needs. It will then be used like:

```
$foo = new Foo;
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $foo->add($d);
}
echo $foo->asXML();
```

If you want to create the next document, **don't reuse `$foo`**, instantiate a `new Foo`.

Comment: Ok I just noticed I made an error in my example. Because the xml would always be the same an I could not use the same object for a different xml again (if that's what Signleton means). But I guess could solve that with cleaning up the xml in the asXML method with $output = $this->xml; $this->xml = ""; $this->create_header(); return $output; or something, right?

Comment: Mmm, no, probably the exact opposite. You seem to do `new Foo` exactly *once*, and then to generate multiple different XML documents with it, right? *That* is a singleton (== only one instance of the class). What I'm proposing it a *single-use object* if you will; instantiate a new object for each document you want to generate. That's simpler code *and* more OOP.